# Mybatis inline type handler for select statements

Tags: java, mybatis

there is simple select

```
<select id = "getWidgetConfig" resultType="com.comp.entity.widgets.cnfg.Widget">
    SELECT `json_config`
    FROM   `widget_config`
    WHERE  `widget_id` = #{widgetId} 
</select>
```

where `json_config` is string value.

Can i bind type/result handler(inline) to convert json_config value into my entity Widget using my handler?

I can do this inline for update/insert statements

```
INSERT INTO `widget_config` 
    (
        `json_config`
    ) 
VALUES 
    ( 
        #{widget,typeHandler=com.comp.mybatis.handlers.widget.WidgetTypeHandler} 
    )
```

How can i do similar for select statements?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to use type handlers on the top level in select. But you can approach this a bit by using result map with constructor:

```
<resultMap id="widgetMap" type="Widget">
  <constructor>
     <arg column="json_config" javaType="string"/>
  </constructor>
</resultMap>

<select id="getWidgetConfig" resultMap="widgetMap">
   SELECT `json_config`
    FROM   `widget_config`
    WHERE  `widget_id` = #{widgetId} 
</select>
```

The potential downside is that you need to have parsing logic in constructor of `Widget`. If this not an option one way to overcome this is to create copy constructor for `Widget` and change mapping like this:

```
<resultMap id="widgetMap" type="Widget">
  <constructor>
     <arg column="json_config" javaHandler="com.comp.mybatis.handlers.widget.WidgetTypeHandler"/>
  </constructor>
</resultMap>
```

You need make sure `Widget` has appropriate copy constructor that takes value of type `Widget` and creates a copy (it may probably reuse internals of the passed `Widget` if they are immutable).